# How can a C# windows service pull thumbnails out of videos?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am writing a windows service observing a network directory for incoming videos recorded by the company's surveillance cameras.
They are then populated into a database and inspected using a counterpart GUI WPF application by a co-worker every morning.

I intend to produce a small thumbnail image of every video right away, since greater amounts of videos are being produced every day. The person watching can then much easier distinguish videos worth seeing from ones that aren't by having a glance at their thumbnails.

My first approach was the MediaToolkit NuGet package (ffmpeg wrapper), however it produces a full resolution thumbnail, so I strive against using it. Next, I tried the MediaPlayer class, that opens the video file and produces a scaled screenshot. This did work in a GUI test environment, it failed inside a windows service:

```
var _player = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer { ScrubbingEnabled = true };
var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(...);
var dv = new DrawingVisual();

using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
    dc.DrawVideo(_player, new Rect(...));
```

It would be my goal to have the MediaPlayer approach running functionally inside a service. However, another working method that can produce scaled thumbnails, without a user having to open a GUI application, would also be in my favor. Thanks in advance.